# Apache2 Web Server In Linux Ubuntu

Tags: apache-http-server, webserver, http, ubuntu-14.04

I'm trying to create a web server on my linux virtual machine. It all OK, but when I try to access it from internet via my public IP address, I just see a loading page in my browser. I have tried turning network connection type into `Bridge` and adding these lines to my `apache2.conf` file:

```
Order allow,deny
Allow from all
```

I just can't find the problem. what can I do?

Comment: There is no problem with web server on LAN. The problem is accessing it from the internet

Comment: Yes its a virtual machine. And i did port forwarding in my router settings. Its all good. But it stays in loading screen. When i try to access it from internet. It works perfectly in LAN network

Comment: when you connect to the external IP, are you doing it from wiithin your LAN? if so, its likely that your router does not support "hairpinning", and without it, you cannot access port forward rules on the exterior interface of the router when you are coming from the interior interface. so are you testing from some other location?

Comment: Yes. I test it with my iphone cellular data.

Comment: can you see the webserver port if you check with canyouseeme.org? if you run `sudo netstat -ntlup | grep 80` what ip address is listening on port 80? is it '127.0.0.1', your LAN IP, or '0.0.0.0'?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My Problem Was My ISP. It Blocked My Port 80. Solved With A Simple Port Forwarding